# Create pdf file dynamically in vb.net for .net 1.1 framework

Tags: vb.net, pdf, visual-studio-2003

I need to create a pdf file dynamically in vb.net. It needs to contain several images and lines of text.

I am using VS 2003, so whatever solution I use will need to be compatible with the .net 1.1 framework.

The current method I am using is [wpcubed](http://www.wpcubed.com/products/wpdf/index.htm), but this requires that all images be converted to bmp format before adding them to the pdf, which can be extremely slow when dealing with a large number of images.

I am aware that there are an awful lot of other 3rd party products that claim to do this, and I have had a search through them. But without registering, downloading, installing and writing code to use each of them in turn, it is very difficult to differentiate between them. So far I have looked into [evo pdf](http://www.evopdf.com/) and [pdfsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/Default.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1),[tallcomponents](http://www.tallcomponents.com/webtopdf1.aspx), [dynamicpdf.com](http://www.dynamicpdf.com/) but none seem to work with .net 1.1. (Although they don't make this abundantly clear.)

Has anyone else found a method that works and they would recommend (a *free* one-if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this point in time, I would start looking for legacy versions of PDF creation libraries, as it is unlikely any new development will be focused on the 1.x framework. ABCpdf used to support .NET 1.x, but I am not sure you can find an older version.

The PDF specification is open, so you can create your own. the problem is it will takes tons of time. Bearing this in mind, I would look for a PDF library that works, even if it costs money, as the few hundred dollars/euros spent on a component is far cheaper than coding it.

Best sources for open source: SourceForge, CodePlex, Google Code, sometimes Code Project (not as much for complete libraries, however).

Comment: I've contacted ABCpdf. They do a legacy version, which supports 1.1 framework. But it is not fully supported.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a version of XSL-FO done for .NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fop-dotnet).
Maybe that will do what you want